# passing command line arguments to awk in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line-arguments

## Background information:

I am trying to write a small shell script, which searches a pattern (string) in a .fas-file and prints the line and position, where the pattern was found. The following code snippet works, when I call the shell script:

### Script (search.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

awk 's=index($0, "CAATCTCC"){print "line=" NR, "start position=" s}' 100nt_upstream_of_mTSS.fas
```

### Command line call:

```
$ ./search.sh
```

## First problem:

When I change the script to:

```
awk 's=index($0, "CAATCTCC"){print "line=" NR, "start position=" s}'
```

and do the following command line call in my bash:

```
$ ./search.sh 100nt_upstream_of_mTSS.fas
```

"nothing" happens (something is running, but it takes way too long and no results come up, so terminate the process).

## Worth to know:

- I am in the directory, where search.sh is located
- the file 100nt_upstream_of_mTSS.fas is located there, too
- search.sh is executable

I might be "screen blind", but I can't find the reason, why I am unable to pass a command line argument to my script.

---

## Solution - see comments

## Note: Only the first occurence of the pattern in a line is found this way.

---

## Second problem:

Furthermore, I would like to make the motif (the string) I search for variable. I tried this:

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
MOTIF=$2
awk 's=index($0, "$MOTIF"){print "line=" NR, "start position=" s}' "$FILE"
```

### Command line call:

```
$ ./search.sh 100nt_upstream_of_mTSS.fas CAATCTCC
```

Idea: First command-line argument worked and was substitued correctly. Why is the second one not substituted correctly?

## Solution so far:

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
awk -v s="$2" 'i=index($0, s){print "line: " NR, "pos: " i}' "$file"
```

### Testing:

Testfile (test.txt):

1 GAGAGAGAGA

2 CTCTCTCTCT

3 TATATATATA

4 CGCGCGCGCG

5 CCCCCCCCCC

6 GGGGGGGGGG

7 AAAAAAAAAA

8 TTTTTTTTTT

9 TGATTTTTTT

10 CCCCCCCCGA

```
 $ ./search.sh test.txt GA
```

will print:

line: 1 pos: 1

line: 4 pos: 2

line: 6 pos: 1

line: 9 pos: 2

line: 10 pos: 9

This script will print line and first match position in the line of only the first character of my pattern. How do I manage to have all results printed and the full pattern being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to pass the Input_file(file which you want to process by script) as an argument, if this is the case then following may help you in same.

```
cat search.sh
#!/bin/bash
variable=$1
awk 's=index($0, "CAATCTCC"){print "line=" NR, "start position=" s}' "$variable"

./search.sh 100nt_upstream_of_mTSS.fas
```

Comment: Yes, this helped! So, awk needs the variable parameter in the end, and I missed that? I feel like I did not fully understand the awk structure yet, but I will do some more research.